# How to call a void method with arguments with a delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arguments, void

I have a void method, this method animates a `UIView` to a point, after a specific time the `UIView` should `animate` to another point, I am trying to do this with a `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:duration target:self selector:@selector(METHOD) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];` but it looks like I can't perform a void with `Arguments`. I need to perform this void:

```
-(void)showNotificationViewWithText:(NSString *)title andTextColor:(UIColor *)titleTintColor andNotificationBackGroundColor:(UIColor *)backGroundColor andDuration:(float)duration direction:(BOOL) up:
```

Or does anyone have a better idea to move a UIView to different points after a delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very flexible method to execute any code after some delay is the GCD function
`dispatch_after()`. It takes a *block* as an argument where you can call
any methods with arbitrary arguments and return types:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do whatever you want, e.g.
    [self showNotificationViewWithText: ....];
});
```

(Tip: Just type "dispatch_after" in the Xcode editor, and let the autocompletion do the rest!)

Comment: This is the neatest solution by far

Answer (score 2):

You can use [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a) method of NSObject class.

```
 NSDictionary *obj = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:title,@"title",titleTintColor,@"titleTintColor",backGroundColor,@"backGroundColor",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:duration],@"duration",[NSNumber numberWithBool:up],@"up" nil];
 [self performSelector:@selector(showNotificationViewWithText:) withObject:obj afterDelay:2.0];  

-(void)showNotificationViewWithText:(NSDictionary *)arg
{
    NSDictionary *title = [arg objectForkey:@"title"];
    UIColor      *titleTintColor = [arg objectForkey:@"titleTintColor"];
    UIColor      *backGroundColor = [arg objectForkey:@"backGroundColor"];
    float        duration = [arg objectForkey:@"duration"];
    BOOL         up = [arg objectForkey:@"up"];

    //code
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks but I have multiple objects and there is no method with objects

Comment: You can pass NSDictionary of arguments.

Comment: You'll eventually get this to work but [Martin R's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19616508/80425) is far superior.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple when scheduling timer just pass nstimer arguement. Try like this:-

```
     [NSTimer    
   scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:duration 
    target:self selector:@selector(METHOD:) 
   userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


  -(void)METHOD:(NSTimer*) timer
  {
 // your code
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or does anyone have a better idea to move a UIView to different points
>   after a delay?

If you animate the view you can specify a delay right in the animation method

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```